# Android Studio , on windows : JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH

Tags: android, android-studio, java-home

I am trying to build my Android app on the command line using Gradle commands. On executing the **.gradlew build**  I am getting the error below:

> ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.
>
> Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the location of your Java installation.

but I think I have already set the JAVA_HOME Path. If I echo %JAVA_HOME% in a separate cmd.exe window I get:

```
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre
```

[image: The location above is set as the JDK location]

I have to point the JAVA_HOME to the JRE provided by Android and not the system Java, right?

Also, when I run the java command, it shows

> 'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or a batch file

```
java  -version
java version "1.8.0_271"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_271-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.271-b09, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Please clarify?

Comment: you are pointing to a jre instead of jdk. Anyway the path there should be something like `/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk`. On Windows it will be a bit different

Comment: what happens if you run `java -version`?

Comment: i get this : 'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: so your `JAVA_HOME` is not correct

Comment: when you install Android Studio, it installs a JDK. Find where it is. I can't tell you because it looks like you are using Windows and I'm using MacOS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understood your problem, add your JDK (Not JRE) path to the PATH variable in environment variables. Then run the `java` command, and it should run. And whenever you post a question, please do make sure that you mention details like what happens when you run `java` command :)

Comment: Thanks works fine now !  I get this after i set the path when i do where is java  : >where is java
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java.exe  (bot sure which one  it is taking, I hope the second one)

Comment: For starting, Android Studio takes its own JDK. For building and gradle, it takes from your PATH or JAVA_HOME variable. It doesn't matter if the JDK is same for both. Anyways, happy to help :)

Answer (score 5):

Quick answer:: change JAVA_HOME variable to \jbr
[image]

- **More details:**

Seems like it has to do with Android studio installer.
if you will look closely into your "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin"
**folder it will probably be empty!**

now check "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin"
you will see many java related ".exe" files and other files.
change JAVA_HOME variable to point to the jbr.

make sure your "Path" variable also contain a %JAVA_HOME%\bin variable:
[image]

Comment: Worked for me. This is the most up to date answer. \jre being practically empty is not mentioned in older comments.

Answer (score 4):

`PATH` environment variable must indicate to the **\bin** directory of your `JAVA_HOME`, for example they should look like this:

**JAVA_HOME: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301"

PATH: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\bin"**

Note that the `PATH` variable has other values too and you must **append** your value to it.